# CakePHP 3 DeleteAll where first 4 letters are not http

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

How do i create this SQL  statement with cakephp 3;

```
 delete FROM bookmarks WHERE substring(url , 4) != 'http'
```

Ive tried;

```
$this->Bookmark->deleteAll('substring(Bookmark.url,4) !=' => 'http',false);
```

Cakephp doesnt like the Substring or LEFT() function

Comment: "_doesn't like_" is not a proper problem description! Despite maybe being answerable as it stands, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens, and what you'd expect to happen instead.

Comment: Also, probably kind of a duplicate of **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30845997/how-to-genereate-sql-function-calls-with-the-cakephp-query-builder**.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$this->Bookmark->deleteAll([
    'NOT' => ['SUBSTRING(url, 1, 4)' => 'http'],
]);
```

Comment: This will generate invalid SQL, as in `DELETE` queries the condition key is subject to alias stripping, which basically works like "_give me everything after the possible dot_", so that you'll end up with something like `WHERE NOT (url, 4) = 'http')`. It will work without alias, but using an expression that would support auto quoting and dialect transforming might be the better/more portable choice (yeah I know, `SUBSTRING` isn't yet subject to transforming). On a side note, it needs to be `1, 4`, not just `4`.

Comment: yes it made a bad query not sure how to fix it. It seems to ignore substring SQL function.

output;

DELETE FROM 
  bookmarks 
WHERE 
  NOT (url, 4) = 'http'